# MongoDB query with $exists and $elemMatch doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

E.g. I have Java objects:

```
public class Foo {
   private Example example;
}
```

```
public class Example {
   private String str1;
   private String str2;
}
```

Field *example* can be null.

I need to get all *Foo* objects where *str1* contains e.g. "text". According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) I tried:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'example' : { $exists : true, $elemMatch : { str1 : { $regex: '.*?0.*'} } } }")
```

but it returns empty Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the query in the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepo extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

    @Query("{ 'example' : { $exists : true }, 'example.str1' : { $regex: ?0 } }")
    List<Foo> findByExamplePropertyRegex(String regexStr);
}
```

Sample four documents in `foo` collection:

```
{ "example" : { "str1" : "apple", "str2" : "rose" } },
{ "example" : { "str1" : "pineapple", "str2" : "jasmine" } },
{ "other": "stuff" },
{ "example" : null }
```

Run the query from Spring Boot application using `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Autowired
private FooRepo repo;

// ...
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    String regexStr = "apple"; // -or- "in"
    List<Foo> list = repo.findByExamplePropertyRegex(regexStr);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output will be two documents with the `regexStr` is "apple", and one document with input "in".

Also, see: [$regex operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html).

Comment: Of course I had this query in Repository. Unfortunately Your query also returns empty Page.

Comment: You have to explain little more. What are the documents in your collection? And what is your query?

Comment: The code I had posted is a working sample; it returns values as per the query and the sample documents. Your two Java POJO classes need to be complete for the code to work. The classes need a constructor with the arguments, getter and setter methods, and an overridden `toString` method to get the result object values print to the console. See this [Spring Data MongoDB Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.repositories) documentation; it also has some examples of creating the POJO classes used with the queries.

Comment: I edited the code for typing errors: "str-1" and "str-2" changed to "str1". and "str2" respectively.

Comment: My models have constructors, getters, etc. After your response my repository method looks like this:
**@Query(value = "{ 'example' : { $exists : true, $elemMatch : { example.str1 : { $regex: ?0} } } }")
Page<Foo> methodName(String str1);**
I want to return this in JSON, but Page content is empty. For test I get All elements from my db and filter them in stream to check that really needed items exists - and them exists. I have been using MongoDB for some time, but I've never had this type of situation before. I think the problem may be a combination of _$exists_ and _$elemMatch_.

Comment: This is the first issue in your query: the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html) query operator is used with _arrays_. And, you are trying to use it on a _string_ data type.

Comment: The second issue with your query: The `example.str1 ` field reference in the query must be within single quotes (the quotes are missing). See the query I had posted in my answer, above.

Comment: There is an extra  closing `}` in my query posted as answer; It is removed now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just like you wrote, problem was in using $elemMatch.