# Mongodb and Spring, best way to search for person through partial first or last name

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, mongodb

I have a react app that is using spring as the back end. I have a search bar that is able to retrieve people by doing  findByFirstName(String firstName); How can I have the search find by either first name , last name, or part of the name?

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, String>
{

    List<Users> findByFirstName(String firstName);

}
```

Comment: You can use a Regular Expression (regex) with the repostory's `findBy...` query. See this post for usage: [MongoDB query with $exists and $elemMatch doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099144/mongodb-query-with-exists-and-elemmatch-doesnt-work) _and_ the [using the MongoDB regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

u can use the like operator, look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)